# Profiling the memory used by linux kernel

Tags: bash, memory, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

I have linux kernel 2.6.30 on an ARM based embedded device.

I have to do some kernel memory usage profiling on the device.

I am thinking of monitoring the ps output on various kernel threads and modules while I carry out actions like wifi on/off etc.

Can you suggest me:

Which threads I need to monitor? How to monitor the kernel module memory usage?

Comment: What problems are you facing that makes you want to do the profiling?

Comment: @PavanManjunath basically we want to have as much memory as possible available for application usage. I am trying to figure out some inefficiencies in the way memory is being used up / held by the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes it is useful to get the real info straight from the kernel, I have used this little C program I threw together to get real system info in an output format that is suited for the shell (it compiles down to a pretty small binary if that matters) --

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
struct sysinfo info;
sysinfo(&info);
printf(     "UPTIME_SECONDS=%d\n"
        "LOAD_1MIN=%d\n"
        "LOAD_5MIN=%d\n"
        "LOAD_15MIN=%d\n"
        "RAM_TOT=%d\n"
        "RAM_FREE=%d\n"
        "MEMUSEDKB=%d\n"
        "RAM_SHARED=%d\n"
        "RAM_BUFFERS=%d\n"
        "SWAP_TOT=%d\n"
        "SWAP_FREE=%d\n"
        "PROCESSES=%d\n",
        info.uptime,
        info.loads[0],
        info.loads[1],
        info.loads[2],
        info.totalram,
        info.freeram,
        (info.totalram-info.freeram)*info.mem_unit/1024,
        info.sharedram,
        info.bufferram,
        info.totalswap,
        info.freeswap,
        info.procs);
}
```

I use it in the shell like this:

```
eval `sysinfo`
BEFORERAM=$MEMUSEDKB
command &
sleep .1 #sleep value may need to be adjusted depending on command's run time
eval `sysinfo`
AFTERRAM=$MEMUSEDKB
echo RAMDELTA is $(($AFTERRAM - BEFORERAM ))
```